# I am getting "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed" in XCode when trying to build the app

Tags: xcode

```
CodeSign /Users/ompatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MakeThemFall-ckljohmknnkuehgbzbfbwmcmrfpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MakeThemFall.app
    cd "/Users/ompatel/Downloads/2 App First/MakeThemFall/MakeThemFall.spritebuilder"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/ompatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MakeThemFall-ckljohmknnkuehgbzbfbwmcmrfpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MakeThemFall.app

/Users/ompatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MakeThemFall-ckljohmknnkuehgbzbfbwmcmrfpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MakeThemFall.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: try **Clean Build Folder** (Option+Shift+Command+K) .. it will remove everything unlike **Clean** which will remove files in the build folder

Answer (score 1):

It seems one or more of your files contain any additional extended attributes. This error pops up starting from OSX Sierra through security hardening.

See apples tech note and solution here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html

> This is a security hardening change that was introduced with iOS 10, macOS Sierra, watchOS 3, and tvOS 10.
>
> Code signing no longer allows any file in an app bundle to have an extended attribute containing a resource fork or Finder info.
>
> To see which files are causing this error, run this command in Terminal:
>
> $ xattr -lr path_to_app_bundle
>
> replacing path_to_app_bundle with the path to your actual app bundle
>
> You can also remove all extended attributes from your app bundle with the xattr command:
>
> $ xattr -cr path_to_app_bundle
>
> Note that browsing files within a bundle with Finder's Show Package Contents command can cause Finder info to be added to those files. Otherwise, audit your build process to see where the extended attributes are being added

After that command do a product > clean and try again.

Note: Saving your project in a Dropbox will always add extended attributes but you may deactivate this behaviour in Dropbox settings

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the build folder and run the project again.

```
Command + Shift + Alt + K
```